# MRTG - Scale Max Speed according to bandwidth usage

Tags: mrtg

In the network graph it shows Max Speed: 1000.0 Mbits/s but the usage is very low. Can the Max Speed instead show less, e.g. 250 Mbits?

[image]

Or this second example: Max Speed is 1000 but now the traffic is around 5000 KB/s, so is it possible to get the Max Speed to show around 100 MB?

[image]

Comment: It's possible get that max speed automatic? Increasing the max speed when the bandwidth is increasing?

Comment: Presumably the 1000 Mb/s represents the maximum bandwidth of your NIC. So with the current graphs, you can see that the bandwidth usage is low, compared to what is available. If you scale it down, then the graph might be misleading, and make a viewer think that relatively more bandwidth is being used than is actually being used.

Comment: Yeah, I understand what are you telling me. Thanks you so much Michael!!